# what is the expected number of comparisons made before the algorithm terminates?

Tags: algorithms

How to approach this question ? I have no idea regarding the method to be applied for solving such kinds of problems .

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can learn [the meaning of (mathematical) expectation at wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/High_School_Mathematics_Extensions/Discrete_Probability#Expectation) or check [its definition at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Definition).

A reasonable assumption is that each combination of the positions of the two x's has the same probability. There are total $\binom{n}{2}$ combinations. Among them, there are $n-i$ combinations in which the first occurrence of $x$ appears at the $i$-th position, each of which requires $i$ comparisons since the algorithm stops once it have found the the first occurrence of $x$.  Let us compute **the expectation**.

$$\qquad \begin{align} E = i \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n-i}{\binom{n}{2}} &= \frac{1}{\binom{n}{2}}\left(n\sum_{i=1}^ni -\sum_{i=1}^ni^2 \right)\\
  &=  \frac{1}{\binom{n}{2}}\left(\frac{n^2 (n+1)}{2} - \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\right)\\
  &=\frac{n+1}{3}
\end{align}$$

Given that simple answer, we will wonder if there is **a simple explanation**. Indeed, there is one. The array $A$ is separated into three parts by the two $x$'s. The total number of values in those three part is $n-2$. Those three parts are symmetric with respect to the number of values in them. So the expected length of the first part is $(n-2)/3$. Adding the one comparison that finds $x$ made right after the end of the first part, we find the expected number of comparisons made by the algorithm is $(n+1)/3$.

In particular, the answer to the original question, "for $n=5$" is $(5+1)/3=2$.

Here is **a generalized version of the problem**. What is the expected number of comparisons made by an algorithm that stops right after it have found the $k$-th occurrence of $x$ in an array of $n$ numbers where $x$ appears $m$ times. It is left as an easy exercise for our readers to find its answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute expectation by its definition. First compute the probaility of the first occurences would be in position $i$. As we have $\binom{n}{2}$ in total number of possibilities, this probaility is $\frac{n-i}{\binom{n}{2}}$. Hence the expectation is $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n-i}{\binom{n}{2}} \times i = O(n)$ which $i$ inside the sum is the number of comparisons.